# Sphinx search, partial search on numeric keywords?

Tags: linux, search, sphinx

I'm currently testing sphinx, So I'm still reading up and getting to grips with the terminology and usage.

Sphinx 2.0.1-id64-beta (r2792)

I've setup sphinx to use

```
morphology              = stem_en
min_stemming_len        = 2
min_word_len            = 3
min_infix_len           = 2
enable_star             = 1
```

**Simplified data set**

```
---------------------------------------------
| id  | searchdata                          |
| 1   | lots of text 00AA0000 00AA4500 AA01 |
| 2   | lots of text 01AA1000 00AA3400 AA21 |
| 3   | lots of text 10AA3000 00AA2300 AA41 |
| 4   | lots of text 02AA4050 00AA1000 AA50 |
---------------------------------------------
```

The query I am trying to perform is as follows

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE MATCH('*AA0*')
```

There are no results returned for the above query.

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE MATCH('*00AA0*')
```

Tho there are results returned for the above query.

Do I need to add a list of custom keywords eg: "00AA000", How would I do that?

I'd appreciate any help.
Regards 
dax

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using stemming and infix on the same index. Not going to work well.

Try removing stemming.